# print reduce SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python

When I call this method patternFinder() I got a error like this

```
def patternFinder():
    avgaLine=((bid+ask)/2)
    x=len(avgaLine)-30
    y=11

    while y<x:
        outcomeRange=avgaLine[y+20:y+30]
        currentPoint=avgaLine[y]

        print reduce((lambda x,y:x+y,outcomeRange)/len(outcomeRange))
        print (currentPoint)
        print ('_________')

        time.sleep(5555)
```

I get this error:

> File `<ipython-input-66-a32566f8689e>`, line 21 
>   print reduce((lambda x,y:x+y,outcomeRange)/len(outcomeRange)) 
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

[image]

Comment: You are using Python 2 syntax with Python 3 if I had to guess. Also you are dividing inside the reduce and not outside.

Comment: which python version are you using? Python 3 or Python 2? if python 3, the print statement needs parenthesis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not the correct way to use `reduce` (the division should be done *after* the reduction), and besides you don't even need to use `reduce` in here. If you want to calculate an average, try this instead:

```
print( sum(outcomeRange) / len(outcomeRange) )
```

By the way, beware of integer division. Make sure that `outcomeRange` contains at least one decimal value, or that you imported the current division function:

```
from __future__ import division
```

Answer (score 1):

`reduce` takes two separate arguments, function and iterable. So, you line should be

```
reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,  outcomeRange/len(outcomeRange))
```

However, also make sure that your `outcomeRange` is a numpy array, otherwise you'll get another syntax error for trying to divide it by a number. Otherwise, convert the division to `[x/len(outcomeRange) for x in outcomeRange]`

In that case, it would be better to divide by the lenght *after* the summation is done, so, you could write

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, outcomeRange) / len(outcomeRange)
```

Comment: Pretty sure the division needs to be out of the reduce if anything.

Comment: @kabanus: it not part of the reduce, it's part of the expression producing the iterable.

Comment: I think OP is calculating an average, besides, if `outcomeRange` is not a `numpy` array that division is a syntax error.

Comment: @kabanus: I have already written that it's a syntax error if it's not numpy, and provided alternative syntax

Comment: @kabanus: the OP has mixed mixed up parentheses, so it's impossible to know what the exact order of the operations should be.

Comment: Actually, in the alternative syntax (which I missed, sorry) you are dividing the some thing `len(outcomeRange)` times, instead of just dividing the sum once. That is why I said it probably needs to be after the summation.

Comment: @kabanus: i know, but the whole thing is pointless anyway, the OP is just doing it for practice (otherwise, it would be just `sum(x)`). However, i added your alternative in the answer

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely using Python 3+, which means that the syntax of your `print` statement is incorrect. It needs to be in parentheses:

```
print(reduce((lambda x,y:x+y,outcomeRange)/len(outcomeRange)))
```

You've done it correctly in the other 2 `print` statements, I guess you've just missed it here.

Answer (score 0):

For `Python 3.8` (Jupyter Notebook Anaconda)

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np
import time

def bytespdate2num(b):
    return mdates.datestr2num(b.decode('utf-8'))

date, bid, ask = np.loadtxt('GBPUSD1d.txt', unpack=True,
                            delimiter=',', converters={0:bytespdate2num})

def percentChange (startPoint, currentPoint):
    return ((float(currentPoint)-startPoint)/startPoint)*100.0

def patternFinder():
    avgLine = ((bid+ask)/2)
    x = len(avgLine) - 30

    y = 11
    while y < x:
        p1 = percentChange(avgLine[y-10], avgLine[y-9])
        p2 = percentChange(avgLine[y-10], avgLine[y-8])
        p3 = percentChange(avgLine[y-10], avgLine[y-7])
        p4 = percentChange(avgLine[y-10], avgLine[y-6])
        p5 = percentChange(avgLine[y-10], avgLine[y-5])
        p6 = percentChange(avgLine[y-10], avgLine[y-4])
        p7 = percentChange(avgLine[y-10], avgLine[y-3])
        p8 = percentChange(avgLine[y-10], avgLine[y-2])
        p9 = percentChange(avgLine[y-10], avgLine[y-1])
        p10 = percentChange(avgLine[y-10], avgLine[y])

        outcomeRange = avgLine[y+20:y+30]
        currentPoint = avgLine[y]

        print (sum(outcomeRange) / len(outcomeRange) )
        print (currentPoint)
        print (' ____')

        print (p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10)
        y += 1
        time.sleep(5555)

patternFinder()
```

**Output**

```
1.553601

1.553555

-0.001930961683282023 -0.0032182694721319405 -0.0032182694721319405 -0.0035400964193622853 -0.003861923366564046 -0.005471058102644308 -0.0061147119970621205 -0.00450557726099615 -0.00450557726099615 -0.004827404208212203
```

Comment: It would be a lot more helpful if you explained what your solution adds to the question and the answers already here.

Comment: It's just a comprehensive version that worked in python 3.8 on Jupyter Notebook Anaconda that I chose to share.